# Samsung file io - can write file but not read back in

Tags: android, file-io, file-permissions

For several weeks, we've been fighting an issue that's been discussed on SO before, but without a working answer in the specific case we've encountered. So after re-reading dozens of threads and trying all the code folks offered, I'm asking for your assistance, please.  (BTW, forget *asking* Samsung: they proved way less than helpful. )

**OS** : 4.0.x through 4.2.x (API lvls 14 - 17)

**Devices** : **Samsung S3** which have /storage/sdcard0  (all we tested do.)

... as opposed to the older */mnt/sdcard* or */storage/sdcard*  (note lack of trailing zero).

Use any flavor of

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
// e.g .getPath() .getName() etc.

// or

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() ...
```

or use a media URI to inform system of file location. (Astounding that THAT fails too.)

Now save a file - you'll see it show up in the DDMS file explorer. And you can pull it via ADB to verify. But just try reading that same file back in - using the same app that you wrote it with in the first place !  ENOENT - file not found. Hardcode the path, append '/external_sd/' to the path the os call gives above (Sumsung says this is needed - but it doesn't do squat.)

Change 'sdcard0' to 'sdcard' as some have suggested ... tried all that too. ZILCH.

Permissions, etc are all correct of course ( since when could a process write a file but not read it !?) .

USB cable connected or not, debug mode or not, "real app" vs developer app (untrusted app) - results all the same: **ENOENT** )

Any ideas or suggestions on how to proceed here?

(With a sledge hammer in hand, staring intently at a new SG3 ... And, SAMSUNG, if you are reading this: "/storage/sdcard0/external_sd/myFileFoo.txt" does NOT work.)

```
/** 
 *
 * [Edit - added sample of failing code, as requested]
 */

public void testFile () {

      ImageView image ; 
      String m_Path = "/SamsuxS3/" ; // more fun than a barrel of NULLs
      String m_MyFile = "myFileFoo.jpg" ;

      image = (ImageView) findViewById ( R.id.imageView1 ) ; 

////   Test 0:
       m_Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() ;   

////  Test 1:        
//       String getPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();  // fails
//       m_Path = getPath ;

////  Test 2:        
//       String getName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName() ; //fails
//       m_Path = getName ;    

////  Test 3:        
//       String defPics = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;  // fails
//       m_Path = m_path + "/" + defPics + "/" ;     

////  Test 4:        
//       m_Path = "/storage/sdcard0/" ;  // fails

////  Test 5:        
//       m_Path = "/storage/sdcard0/external_sd/" // Samsung says so, but it fails too.   

////  Test 6: now we're really hacking ...
//      m_Path = "/storage/sdcard/"  // Fails (although sdcard is mounted as sdcard0 - hmmm)   

      InputStream fIn = null;
      File fileIn = new File(m_Path, m_MyFile);   

      try { //// This is only one way many attempts...  

            //// 1) just grab an image from a known resource, 
            //// 2) try to save it, 
            //// 3) then read it back into an ImageView.

            //// External storage must be mounted or this fails.

            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.somepicture) ;  // works
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileIn); // OK

            byte[] data = new byte[is.available()]; // OK
            is.read(data);  // OK
            os.write(data); // OK - DDMS file explorer verfied
            is.close();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error writing to " + m_Path, e.toString());  // never happened yet
        }

        //// now we step into the SamDung  
        ////
        InputStream fIn2 = null;  //// Well, it's redundant but ...
        File fileIn2 = new File(m_Path, m_MyFile);   

        try {
             fIn2 = new FileInputStream (fileIn2) ;   
              //
              // Here be the Dragons...
              //       
              // Next line WORKS on every device EXCEPT a Samsung - blows up w/ ENOENT !
              // 
             image.setImageBitmap ( BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fIn2) );  
             fIn2.close ();                                             
        } catch (Exception IOError) { 
             Log.d("WTF? I'm not moving to Korea: ",  IOError.toString()) ; 
        }  
  }
```

Comment: Post a sample app that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thought it was clear, but as you requested ... see edit at the bottom of the OP. thanks - H

Comment: It's more that if I'm going to shell out $400+ to buy a device to try to reproduce your problem, it'd be nice to be **very very certain** that I am not wasting my time and money. That's why I asked for -- and continue to ask for -- for **a sample app** (i.e., a full Android project). IOW, if you want others to be able to reproduce your problem, to try to help you get past it, the more you can give us that will clearly reproduce that problem, the better.

Comment: Oops - well, I was chastised by several people here that posting an entire app was too much fluff! All that's needed in addition to the code above is an arbitrary .jpg in the res dir, and layout xml with an image view and a button to call testFile().  (BTW, I'd not waste money on the S3 - I have three and want to smash them all :-O)

Comment: "I was chastised by several people here that posting an entire app was too much fluff!" -- well, you wouldn't post it all inline. I was thinking more of a one-off GitHub repo, or a link to a ZIP file, or something. "I'd not waste money on the S3" -- yes, well, it's these sorts of things that make me want/need to get one.

Answer (score 3):

The [proper way to write a file on Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html) for Android 3.0+, where you intend to use the file again quickly, is:

```
  os.flush();
  os.getFD().sync();
  os.close();
```

for a `FileOutputStream` named `os`.

Using this change, your example code works with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, on a Samsung Galaxy S3, running Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but reading the file back in quickly was not the problem... it was getting it to read back in _at all_ using a "known" path and filename. Samsung has errantly promulgated that we have to append "external_sd/" to the path returned - regardless if that path is via String ~.getAbosultePath() or File ~.getExternalStorageDirectory();  Even their own sample code fails on 4.1.1 ... haven't tried on 4.2.2 yet.

Comment: @HowardPautz: Try the recipe anyway. I was able to reproduce your problem, and this recipe fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, as I said in the OP, I tried many things, including the same thing as your recipe. Out of consideration for your efforts on my behalf, which I do appreciate, I did try your recipe ("again") before responding before earlier, of course.  It still doesn't work.  ... strong winds are blowing that Samsung wants to out-Google Google, dumping Android in favor of Tizen ... our pain has only begun ... try using their "webkit" if you don't believe the rumors.

Comment: @HowardPautz: You are welcome to back up your claims by posting somewhere **a complete Android project** that fails to work. That could be in the form of a ZIP file, a GitHub repo, etc.

Comment: The problem is that the OP problem happens on a handful of Samsung S3's with 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 but not other S3's with the same versions of the OS. The problem ones are T-mobile. I've already wasted too much time on it, am throwing in the towel, and will just check and hardcode for those phones. That works, but it's a hack. If I do have another odd one like this, I'll set up a GitHub repo w/complete code (I have not had need to do that yet). Thanks again for your time.

Comment: BTW, I'm not the only one having these issues.  Google Samsung Webkit and Samsung Camera ... even here on SO, there at least a dozen threads about Camera Intent data coming back as null and/or the .Path() calls not working ... not to mention Samsung's partitioning  of their devices memory/storage in counterintuitive ways! cheers - H.  REF see for instance comments on https://github.com/deepwinter/AndroidCameraTester